# How to change The minimap Background color in Monaco index.html

Tags: html, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

[image]

Since, i want it to be transparent this is what i have now, i have readed every topic or etc

```
 monaco.editor.defineTheme('TestMonaco', {
                    base: 'vs-dark',
                    inherit: true,
                    rules: [
                        { token: 'global', foreground: '4060FF', fontStyle: "bold" },
                        { token: 'keyword', foreground: '4060FF', fontStyle: "bold" },
                        { token: 'comment', foreground: '666666' },
                        { token: 'number', foreground: 'd4d4d4' },
                        { token: 'string', foreground: 'd4d4d4' },
                    ],
                                        colors: {
                    'editor.background': '#00000000',
                    'editorLineNumber.foreground': '#949494',
                    'minimap.background': 'd4d4d4',
                }
                });
```

I tried, every toppic answers and css and js edit the workers of the monaco

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me:

```js
monaco.editor.defineTheme('TestMonaco', {
    base: 'vs-dark',
    inherit: true,
    rules: [{ background: '#0000FF' }], // This is needed
    colors: {
        'editor.background': '#000000',
    }
});

monaco.editor.setTheme('TestMonaco');
```

Make sure you remove `'minimap.background': 'd4d4d4'` property and give the rules an object with a background property only don't give it a token, of course you can add it with other rules also.

Note: you can't make the background of minimap transparent, you can remove it if you wish

Comment: I implanted your code, or modified it but it doesn't seem to work it wont load the monaco

Comment: Can minimap be changed to a color then? doesnt need to be transparent if it cant

Comment: @DanielNiewold-RobloxExploi Yes the way i did it change the background color of minimap i tried this code on monaco playground https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html and it worked fine

Comment: I assume the 'd4d4d4' should be '#d4d4d4'? I have tried using the `minimap.background` key and it works for me